# Distinguish between temporaries and non-temporaries in function signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, temporary

I want to create a class Bar that can distinguish between temporaries and non-const non-temporaries. According to [this (about 25% down the page)](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html%22this%22), I can get away with this if the second StealPointer takes a const reference (to a pointer in my case), but in my code it just uses the StealPointer(Foo*&& foo) version regardless of how it is called.

```
class Foo {};

class Bar {
 public:
  // For when StealPointer(new Foo()); is called. Bar instance then owns the
  // pointer.
  void StealPointer(Foo*&& foo) {} // Get the temporaries only.

  // For when a Foo* already exists and is passed in StealPointer(my_foo_ptr);
  // Takes ownership and invalidates the pointer that the caller once had.
  void StealPointer(Foo*&) {} // Get lvalues only.
};
```

Can I do this? Is there a way to do this that only requires one function? If it matters, Bar is going to store the pointer in a unique_ptr and I would like to avoid the additional syntax of passing in a unique_ptr or making the caller do something with std::move. I can't just pass the pointers by reference, because temporaries of type Foo* can't be converted to Foo*&.

Comment: I assume that Bar is either a struct or the StealPointer methods should be public.

Comment: `template <typename Ptr> void StealPointer(Ptr&& foo) : uniqptr{std::move(foo)} {};`  would, I believe, handle every case you're worried about

Comment: You could do this or you could just have the function that takes an rvalue reference and if you call `StealPointer` with an `lvalue` you will have to wrap it with `std::move` otherwise it will be a compile time error.

Comment: @TrevorHickey - Yes, public. Got carried away in my attempt to simplify.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a `unique_ptr` parameter? That's exactly what your function should take if it's going to assume ownership. And your last sentence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Praetorian - I didn't want the syntax for using this function to be as verbose as StealFoo(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()));  To try and clarify my last sentence, If I was passing the pointers by reference, which is what my plan was for handing the lvalue case, I would get a compile-time error when trying to pass (new Foo()) because it can't convert Foo* to Foo*&. I believe this is similar to the "cannot bind to a temporary" error.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez - StealPointer isn't a constructor and can't take a base initializer.

Comment: That error doesn't have anything to do with memory not being assigned and whatnot. There are several questions about that error, you should be able to find the answer by searching for what you put in quotes. I don't see a big enough problem with that syntax that it needs to be avoided in favor of inferior solutions, but what about `StealFoo(std::make_ unique<Foo>())`? Write your own `make_unique` if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your function templated and let `std::unique_ptr` worry about those details for you.

```
template <typename Ptr>
void StealPointer(Ptr&& p) // a universal reference, matches *any* type of value
{
    uniqptr = std::move(p); // Works for both rvalues and lvalues
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. Why does the template interpret the type when calling with an lvalue as a constant reference, but without the template it would prefer to use the rvalue reference signature?

Comment: @Chet `&&` has a different meaning when used with templates.  See [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) for an explanation.

Comment: It will take me some time to digest that reference, but this does exactly what I was aiming to do. Thank you so much!